# What is the advantage of namespace in typescript if used as container for types

Tags: typescript, namespaces

Why would I keep a type in a namespace rather than just directly export it.

Example I could do this

```
export interface Document {
  first_name: string
  status: Document.DocumentStatus
}

export namespace Document {
  export type DocumentStatus = 'active' | 'inactive'
}
```

But I could achieve the same result with using namespace

```
export interface Document {
  first_name: string
  status: DocumentStatus
}

export type DocumentStatus = 'active' | 'inactive'
```

What is the advantage of using namespaces in this context?

Comment: AFAIK there is no functional difference.  It's just a question of what organization of your declarations you think is easiest for your users to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, namespaces help with sorting out the purpose of the interface especially when the interfaces start to pile up.

For e.g.

```
    Document.Status
    Document.Content
    Document.Owner
    Person.Name
    Person.Status
    Person.Address
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript `namespace` (formerly `module` and known as "internal module") pre-dates the ES module `import`/`export` syntax and is largely obsolete now. The use of namespace can usually be considered [redundant when using ES modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing). You can still use `namespace` for organizational purposes if you want, but that's largely a personal choice. Note that with ES modules you can still import *as a namespace*, ie `import * as Document from "./Document"` so the use of references like `Document.Status` is not dependent on using a `namespace`. In the end it's really just an organization choice.